# CCScheduler crashes as message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, crash

This may sound like a noob question, because it is. I have tried for days to figure out what I am doing to make it crash, but I can't figure it out.

I have various objects that use CCActions. When the objects need to be removed from screen, I call [spriteObject stopAllActions]; I then release the actions. (I retain the actions in init, as I was trying to avoid this kind of crash).

The program randomly crashes at this line in CCScheduler:

```
[elt->currentTimer release];
```

The error message is that I am sending a message to a deallocated instance. But I can't figure out what gets deallocated when. I retain all the actions I create. I even tried running the program without ever releasing the actions, to see If that was the cause, but it still crashes.

Sometimes it crashes after 20minutes, sometimes after 2 minutes. It is pretty random.
I'm not sure what to put up because the code is pretty spread out.

Basically, I have a Sprite, which contains a "Strategy" object, which contains the CCAction that is running. At run time I create a "strategy" and pass it to the sprite which retains the strategy.

The sprites are not deallocated until the end of program execution.

Any ideas on how I can figure out what is being deallocated, where and why? I really can't figure it out. Not sure what information to put up here. :C

Comment: Please post more codes in order to locate the error. But apparently, the timer is already released before you call `release`

Comment: You can check retain count to see if that is the problem.

Comment: It seems that cocos2d is not expected to be thread safe, so the api shouldn't be accessed from multiple threads. I guess I need to make a design change.

Comment: don't retain actions, don't manually release them either. Sending stopAllActions is enough. If the node running the action gets removed from the node hierarchy, you don't need to manually stop/remove the actions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d is currently not thread safe, and the api's are not expected to be called from other threads.